# Print all the levels of variable with the class factor

Tags: r

I have the data set in which some are factors as well some are numerical/integer, so what should be the command to return levels of only factor class.

```
aa bb cc dd
1  12 P  43
4  23 Q  78
8  34 Q  89
9  86 P  78
7  67 P  98
9  76 Q  74
```

So, now if I want to print all the levels of variables with the class factor, i.e. P and Q in cc, so what should be my R command?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `x[, sapply(x, class) == "factor"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean by "print all the levels of variables with the class factor, i.e. P and Q in cc", but I think you are looking for `subset`:

```
> x
  aa bb cc dd
1  1 12  P 43
2  4 23  Q 78
3  8 34  Q 89
4  9 86  P 78
5  7 67  P 98
6  9 76  Q 74
> subset(x, cc=='P')
  aa bb cc dd
1  1 12  P 43
4  9 86  P 78
5  7 67  P 98
```

Answer (score 0):

The `levels` function shows the levels of a factor variable. Assume your sample data is called `dat`.  To view the levels of the factor columns without showing `NULL` for the non-factor columns, you could do the following.

```
> lapply(dat[sapply(dat, is.factor)], levels) 
# $cc
# [1] "P" "Q"
```

Should there be more than one factor column, the above line will show all of them with their respective column name and levels. Additionally, you can view the entire data set as a list, which will also show the levels of any factor variables.

```
> as.list(dat)
# $aa
# [1] 1 4 8 9

# $bb
# [1] 12 23 34 86

# $cc
# [1] P Q Q P
# Levels: P Q

# $dd
# [1] 43 78 89 78
```